# Using same std::mutex & lock object everywhere for all instances of locking and unlocking in all parallel threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

I've 2 threads which access a shared resource:

**Shared resource is the below Doubly linked list:**

```
std::list<RowColumns> ll;
struct RowColumns
{
   int x;
   float y;
   vector<vector<string> vec2D;
   .....//many other fields;
}
```

Thread1:
Writes data to this shared resource.

Thread 2:
Reads data from this shared resource and writes to a file.

Both threads run in parallel i.e. as and when data is written to shared resource by Thread1 , then thread2 should keep reading the data written and write it to a file, for every "X" time interval.
So, the code of T1 & T2 has many statements where shared resource is accessed. So to avoid hijacking of the shared resource by 1 thread I just lock & unlock for every acess so that I can achieve concurrency and both threads get opportunity to run.

**My query is can I use a same mutex variable everywhere for all instances of locking and unlocking.
Example to make my question more clear:**

> In below example, as you can see, the same mutex object "singleMutex"
>   is used & also the same "lock1" unique_lock() lock object is used in
>   both T1 & T2 threads for all acceses of the different elements of the
>   shared resource. Will Such usage of using the same mutex & the same lock 
>   across all  lock & unlock instances work & really serve the mutex
>   purpose ? As we know mutex variable & lock is not attached to any
>   object or resource, i think it should work. BUt at the same time I was
>   confuse dbecause, if we use same mutex everywhere then where do we
>   need multiple mutextx ?

```
    std::mutex singleMutex;


Thread1():
{
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      while(someCondition())
      {
          std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(singleMutex);
          RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
          lock1.unlock();
          RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
          RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
          RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
          lock1.lock();
          RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
          lock1.unlock();
      }
       RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
       RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
       RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(singleMutex);
       RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
       lock1.unlock();
       RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
       lock1.lock();
       RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
       lock1.unlock();

       RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
       RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
       RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
       lock1.lock();
       RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
       lock1.unlock();
```

Thread_2():

```
{
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();

      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(singleMutex);
      RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
      lock1.unlock();
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      lock1.lock();
      RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
      lock1.unlock();

      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();

      RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
      lock1.unlock();
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      lock1.lock();
      RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
      lock1.unlock();

      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      RunStatement_WITH_NO_SHARED_RESOURCE ();
      lock1.lock();
      RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();
      lock1.unlock();
```

Comment: All access to the *same* shared resource should use the same mutex. If you have multiple shared resources, each can have its own mutex.

Comment: You are not using the same lock (just two locks with the same name) but that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: What if the shared resource is huge  like say in thi sexample, I've the doubly linked list as shared resource. But here eventhough i've ONE SHARED RESOURCE, my each instance of "RunStatement_ACCESSING_SHARED_RESOURCE();" would be accessing different part of this shared resource. For example, the structure has a vector<vectr<string>. So 1 instance can be accessing some row of this 2d vector,another instance another row, another structure variable "int a", etc. Should i consider all these accesses from both threads & several instances within same thread as a single shared resource & use 1 mutex?

Comment: If you indent the code more readers will find it easier to help you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: thanks. How do we define  " same resource" here ? Is the entire doubly linked list a same resource eventhough it has many fileds like structure nodes, each node having vector of vector of strings, integers etc..

Comment: Well if the list is shared (accessed, modified) by multiple threads it has to be protected. Then it depends on the data in the list (the nodes), will multiple threads work on the same node at the same time? Then it needs to be protected as well (which can be a separate mutex from the one protecting the list).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thanks. By Using the same mutex for the entire list, it's ingredients (nodes, contents within nodes etc.), will the mutex not serve it's purpose.  Is it mandatory to use separate mutexes ?  Basically i'm trying to understand, mutexex are not linked to any resource. Then how can we associate a mutex with a variable or object ?

Comment: @MikeMB: I've declared the lock only once in each thread. Then how is it that it's the same lock ?

Comment: The question is `Where do we need multiple mutexes?`; am I correctly understand your question post?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you really understand the concept of a mutex..

A mutex (**mut**ual **ex**clusion) is used to lock the access on a shared resource, e.g. an integer, a list or any object. Even if your resource consists of multiple variables, you only need one mutex.

A good practice is to encapsulate the access on the resource in a function, so you only need to implement the mutex locking once per access function:

```
#include <mutex>

int g_resource = 42;
std::mutex g_mutex;

int getResource()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    return g_resource;
    // auto unlocking, when object 'lock' is destroyed on exit of block
}

void incrementResource()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    g_resource++;
}

//...
```

---

- For primitive datatypes I suggest using `std::atomic<T>`